# Annoy pandas SettingWithCopyWarning, even tried loc[;,]

Tags: python, pandas

```
code_null.loc[:,'code'] = code_null['blockname'].apply(__f,args=(code_name,))

def __f(x, df):
    #markets = ['A','B']
    markets = ['A']
    for market in markets:
        code = df.loc[df.name==x,'code'].tolist()
    if code:
        return ','.join(code)
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Always getting `SettingWithCopyWarning`,

```
.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:537: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Also tried:

```
 code_null.loc[:,'code'] = code_null.loc[:,'blockname'].apply(__f,args=(code_name,))
```

But got same warning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to do, but have you tried `code_null['code'] = code_null['blockname'].apply(__f,args=(code_name,))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
code_null.loc[:,'code'] = code_null['blockname'].apply(__f,args=(code_name,)).copy()
```

Comment: still got the warnning "SettingWithCopyWarning"

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`code_null.loc[:,(code)] = code_null[(blockname)].apply(__f,args=(code_name,))`

### Copy method is not preferred:

The `.copy()` method is not guaranteed and should be avoided per the [DOCS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

#### Prefered method from the docs:

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})

dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 11

dfc
     A  B
0   11  1
1  bbb  2
2  ccc  3
```

Comment: Oops, just meant to use parentheses, I'll edit. Can you share some sample data for testing?